# Blocks are not producing when using --staging flag (in the full node)

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

```
Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xed0a…2e72), finalized #0 (0xed0a…2e72), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xed0a…2e72), finalized #0 (0xed0a…2e72), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
```

I am getting above output if i run (./target/release/substrate --chain=staging) this command in substrate full node.
I also tried to run a private network for staging , the result was same.

In either of the case the network is not producing the blocks.

Can I get any guide how to use staging?
Need to run in production network and I have seen that for production purposes we should use --staging but not --dev and --local. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add a block producer key to your command.

Not exactly sure what the `staging` chain specification looks like, but something like:

```
./target/release/substrate --chain=staging --alice
```

Where we assume Alice is a configured block producer for the chain.

Comment: Error: Service(Client(StateDatabase("Expected pruning mode: constrained")))

Got this error while running the mentioned command